# How to get only one field from firestore query, i am getting all the fields

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I can output all the fields in console, but I want to output only 1. I only want to get the ID field but I somehow cannot do it. The following screenshots shows my code and the output.

[Code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyufR.png)

```
this.afs.collection("accounts",ref=>ref
          .where("email","==", email)) // email of currently logged in
          .get()
          .subscribe(data=>
            data.forEach(element=>
              //console.log(el.data())
              console.log(element.data())
          ));
```

[Output in console:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8v6X.png)

```
{id: '864b7TECyqUdd8Ql7f81saSgoOx2', lastName: '******',
address: '******', contactNo: '******', role: 
'******', …}
address: "******"
contactNo: "******"
email: "******"
firstName: "******"
id: "864b7TECyqUdd8Ql7f81saSgoOx2"
lastName: "******"
role: "******"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Comment: Do you want to get value of a single field from the `data` or get only that field from the server side itself (that is not possible atm using client SDKs)?

Comment: I want to get value of a single field from the data, what code should I use?

Comment: The `element.data()` is just an object. You can use `elemet.data().email` to get email and so for other fields.

Comment: It shows error of 'Object is of type 'unknown'.'. Please help with the proper syntax how to get one field only

Comment: Try `.forEach((element: any) =>` as well ?

Comment: how do i store that in a variable?

Comment: `const varName = element.data().email`?

Comment: it becomes undefined tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore always *retrieves* the complete document from the server, but you can display just one field with:

```
data.forEach(element=>
  console.log(element.data().id)
));
```

Comment: how can i store that element.data().id into a variable?
i tried `const varName = element.data().email` but it stays undefined and unused

Comment: That's a different question, but most likely that you're trying to access the variable outside of the `.subscribe` callback, before it has been set.

Comment: yes, how can i store it in a variable that can be accessed outside the .subscribe?